# Encountering conda environment error (Mac m1)

Tags: terminal, anaconda, conda

I am encountering an error while trying to change conda environments. When I run `conda info --envs`, I get the following error message. Ideas? (in for-dummies format). Thanks!

```
/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
        import urllib3
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
        from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.connectionpool'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1132, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 57, in main_subshell
        p = generate_parser()
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 63, in generate_parser
        p = ArgumentParser(
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 148, in __init__
        self._subcommands = context.plugin_manager.get_hook_results("subcommands")
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 419, in plugin_manager
        from ..plugins.manager import get_plugin_manager
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/plugins/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .hookspec import hookimpl  # noqa: F401
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/plugins/hookspec.py", line 10, in <module>
        from .types import CondaSolver, CondaSubcommand, CondaVirtualPackage
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/plugins/types.py", line 6, in <module>
        from ..core.solve import Solver
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 19, in <module>
        from .index import get_reduced_index, _supplement_index_with_system
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 15, in <module>
        from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 22, in <module>
        from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 28, in <module>
        from ..gateways.connection.download import download
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from pip._vendor.requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 149, in <module>
        from . import packages, utils
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages.py", line 8, in <module>
        locals()[package] = __import__(vendored_package)
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/idna/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from .core import (
      File "/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/idna/core.py", line 3, in <module>
        import unicodedata
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unicodedata'
```

I tried running `$ /Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/bin/conda info --envs` and received another error message. The error comes with an error report that conda is asking me to submit to their maintainers to support improving the tool in the future. Should I submit the report `[y/N]:`? Please help me get this fixed, thanks!

Comment: `/Users/megsmacbookpro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_distutils_hack` - what? This looks very suspicious.

Comment: Yeah, i dont know. I found this but it didn't quite match what I need:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11931

Comment: What we found so far is that conda is using a diff version of python than what python version I'm using. If my explanation makes sense. System is python 3.11, conda using 3.10

Comment: FIXED: What a runaround - but we had to separately remove anaconda/navigator from terminal then all instances. Then went through the process of reinstalling and it seems to be working now. Took hours of googling and thinking, which is almost embarassing.

Comment: @topsail One can always check any file in a Conda environment to determine its provenance with `conda package --which`. In this case, this is distributed with the `setuptools` package (unlikely to be malicious).

Comment: @merv it still looks very suspicious. Horrible name for a package. However good to know about using `package --which` I can't be too hard on the conda folks though - I'm sure they are working hard. I probably would have called it something unhelpful too.

Comment: @topsail not a Conda thing - it's from [the official distribution](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools) from PyPA.